# Spring Expression Language - get system property in Annotation

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

In my controller, I am trying to get `system properties` in Spring annotation. This is the code

`@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('${systemProperties['user.name']}', '')")`

which is throwing `org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelParseException`.
I tried

```
@PreAuthorize("hasPermission('#{systemProperties['user.name']}', '')")
```

but results in same `exception`

What is the syntax for getting system properties inside Spring annotation?

Comment: Shouldn't you use `#{systemProperties` instead of `${systemProperties` ?

Comment: Tried, but getting the same exception

Comment: @Suganthan try the example given and lemme know. Locally it worked, otherwise I will just remove the answer if that is incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
@Component
public class WhateverBean {

    @Value("#{systemProperties['user.name']}")
    private String userName;

    public String getUserName() {
        return userName;
    }

    @PreAuthorize("hasPermission('@whateverBean.getUserName()', '')")
    public void xxx() {
        // ...
    }
}
```